# Format causes a subtraction of exactly 4 hours from the hour field every time

Tags: date, datetime, format, ext.net

For all of my dates, `Format` subtracts **exactly 4 hours** from the hour field.

Here is an example for clarification:

When I retrieve a date in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the date column returns dates in this format: `2014-10-30 11:19:02.733`.

When I execute the same command using sql and display the value in a gridpanel, it is displayed in this format: `2014-10-30T11:19:02.733`.

However, When I try to use `Format="yyyy-M-d, HH:mm"`, the date is returned as `2014-10-30 07:19:02`.

For easier comparison, this is what the difference is:

```
2014-10-30 11:19:02.733
2014-10-30T11:19:02.733
2014-10-30 07:19:02
```

What could cause the removal of **exactly 4 hours** every single time?

Thank you.

Additional code:

```
 <ext:DateColumn ID="Column6" runat="server" Text="When" DataIndex="time" Flex="1" Format="yyyy-M-d, HH:mm" />
```

Comment: just guessing but your DateColumn is probably doing some sort of timezone conversion. try just binding to a formatted string property

Comment: You are right. I changed the timezone on my pc and it consequentially changed the value again. Now I am going to need to find a way around, and see if this is affecting my other columns... ugh!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future:

I found the solution, based on Julien's guess!

I changed the timezone on my pc and it consequentially changed the value again.

It turns out, that the way around this is is to add a `type` to the `modelField`. It would look something like this `<ext:ModelField Name="time" Type="Date" />`.

For some reason, this prevents the client-side time-zone override.